# Unity 3d Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path, antivirus

I am new to Unity. I am getting this error from time to time in Unity ever since I am using it. It says : Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\Folder\ProjectName\Temp\Assembly-CSharp.dll.mdb" is denied

I tried googling, but to no success. I do not get this error on my office PC.

I am using Windows 8 laptop. Have Avast antivirus installed. Unity version is 5. Android sdk version is 2.2.

Reimporting all assets did not help. Even restarting Unity does not stop the error. I have even tried uninstalling my antivirus(though that's a risk), but no use.

Comment: Happened to me too. Have you tried running unity as administrator?

Comment: Tried running as administrator, still gives the error after certain time :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Close unity (check Task Manager to make sure there are no unity instances floating around)
2. Navigate to that particular `\Temp` folder using Windows Explorer,
3. Delete all files
4. Restart unity